# Can't get Wacom Graphire CTE-630BT to work on Mandriva 2010.1 64-bits

Tags: linux

**[SOLUTION]** Install kernel 2.6.34 or newer, or use kernel 2.6.32 or older. 2.6.33 seems to have problems with this pad.

---

I can't get this tablet to properly work. Here are the details:

Tablet: Wacom Graphire CTE-630BT (Wireless over BlueTooth).

Mandriva: 2010.1 Free 64 bits, all repositories configured.

Problem:

- I can only left and right click with
  the pan (stylus)
- I can not move the
  cursor
- No pressure is sensed

What happens:

- The Bluetooth adapter is recognized and working (generic BT adapter)
- gnome-bluetooth finds the divice
- HAL finds the device
- x11-driver-input-wacom is installed
- I can read/write parameters with xsetwacom from the console
- If I change something in 10-wacom.fdi and restart the device, lshal reflects the changes.

Relevant part from lshal:

```
udi = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/bluetooth_acl_13c2033cc7_logicaldev_input' 
  info.capabilities = {'input', 'input.mouse', 'input.tablet'} (string list) 
  info.category = 'input'  (string) 
  info.parent = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/bluetooth_acl_13c2033cc7'  (string) 
  info.product = 'WACOM Pen Tablet'  (string) 
  info.subsystem = 'input'  (string) 
  info.udi = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/bluetooth_acl_13c2033cc7_logicaldev_input'  (string) 
  input.device = '/dev/input/event5'  (string) 
  input.originating_device = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/bluetooth_acl_13c2033cc7'  (string) 
  input.product = 'WACOM Pen Tablet'  (string) 
  input.x11_driver = 'wacom'  (string) 
  input.x11_option.Type = 'stylus'  (string) 
  linux.device_file = '/dev/input/event5'  (string) 
  linux.hotplug_type = 2  (0x2)  (int) 
  linux.subsystem = 'input'  (string) 
  linux.sysfs_path = '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/input11/event5'  (string)
```

My /usr/share/hal/fdi/policy/20thirdparty/10-wacom.fdi XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<!-- this is probably a bit imprecise --> 
<deviceinfo version="0.2"> 
  <device> 
    <match key="info.category" contains="input"> 
      <match key="info.product" contains_outof="Wacom;WALTOP;WACOM"> 
   <merge key="input.x11_driver" type="string">wacom</merge> 
   <merge key="input.x11_option.Type" type="string">stylus</merge> 
      </match> 
    </match> 
    <match key="info.capabilities" contains="serial"> 
      <match key="@info.parent:pnp.id" contains_outof="WACf;FUJ02e5;FUJ02e7"> 
   <append key="info.capabilities" type="strlist">input</append> 
   <merge key="input.x11_driver" type="string">wacom</merge> 
   <merge key="input.x11_options.ForceDevice" type="string">ISDV4</merge> 
   <merge key="input.device" type="copy_property">serial.device</merge> 
      </match> 
    </match> 
    <!-- N-Trig Duosense Electromagnetic Digitizer --> 
    <match key="info.product" contains="HID 1b96:0001"> 
      <match key="info.parent" contains="if0"> 
       <merge key="input.x11_driver" type="string">wacom</merge> 
      </match> 
    </match> 
  </device> 
</deviceinfo>
```

Output from `xinput --list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                       id=2   [master pointer  (3)] 
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4   [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Desktop® 2.10   id=7   [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎜   ↳ Macintosh mouse button emulation           id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎜   ↳ WACOM Pen Tablet eraser                    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎜   ↳ WACOM Pen Tablet cursor                    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎜   ↳ WACOM Pen Tablet pad                       id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎜   ↳ WACOM Pen Tablet                           id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                      id=3   [master keyboard (2)] 
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                id=5   [slave  keyboard (3)] 
    ↳ Power Button                               id=6   [slave  keyboard (3)] 
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Desktop® 2.10   id=8   [slave  keyboard (3)] 
    ↳ Power Button                               id=9   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output from `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0005 Vendor=056a Product=0081 Version=0100 
N: Name="WACOM Pen Tablet" 
P: Phys=00:0B:0D:4C:FD:67 
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/input11 
U: Uniq=00:13:C2:03:3C:C7 
H: Handlers=mouse2 event5 
B: EV=1f 
B: KEY=1c63 70003 0 0 0 0 
B: REL=103 
B: ABS=3000003 
B: MSC=11
```

Note: I can not see any information on the console when I use

```
xxd mouse2
```

or

```
xxd event5
```

(xxd works OK with my real mouse device and keyboard device.)

I would appreciate any help you can offer. I read tens of articles on all kind of forums and of course the official page ... I had no luck.

PS: modifying xorg.conf as described in a different place was also unsuccessful.

**UPDATE**

I installed by hand the latest drivers. Now, /dev/input/event5 and /dev/input/mouse2 receives data from the tablet, and I can see information going on when I touch *and* move the pen on the tablet.

I also can see now the tablet in the hardware list in Mandriva Linux's MCC

However, at linuxwacom.sourceforge.net, they say I can test `xidump -u raw <devicename>` to see what actions X forwards for the tablet. Here, I can see **only** Button Down and Button Up action ... no movement at all.

Also, X.org configuration seems to be ignored ... It is set up as described on the linuxwacom documentation, but with or without it, I have the same situation.

**UPDATE (July the 30th 2010)**

After further investigation, I found out that even if I compile the wacom kernel module from source and use the latest xf86-input-wacom (also compiled from source), I have a module callde **hid_wacom** installed by Mandriva which takes control of the pad. If I remove this, nothing works, not even the clicking with the pan.

I made this tests / combination of modules:
[

```
root@localhost src]# rmmod hid_wacom
[root@localhost src]# lsmod | grep wacom
[root@localhost src]# modprobe wacom
[root@localhost src]# lsmod | grep wacom
wacom                  32589  0
usbcore               210260  11
wacom,snd_usb_audio,snd_usb_lib,btusb,gspca_zc3xx,gspca_main,uhci_hcd,ohci_hcd,ehci_hcd,usbhid
[root@localhost src]# lsmod | grep wacom
hid_wacom               3481  0
wacom                  32589  0
usbcore               210260  11
wacom,snd_usb_audio,snd_usb_lib,btusb,gspca_zc3xx,gspca_main,uhci_hcd,ohci_hcd,ehci_hcd,usbhid
hid                    81725  4 hid_wacom,hidp,usbhid,hid_microsoft
[root@localhost src]# rmmod hid_wacom
[root@localhost src]# lsmod | grep wacom
wacom                  32589  0
usbcore               210260  11
wacom,snd_usb_audio,snd_usb_lib,btusb,gspca_zc3xx,gspca_main,uhci_hcd,ohci_hcd,ehci_hcd,usbhid
```

Following is a partial output of evtest (it may help):

```
Input driver version is 1.0.0
Input device ID: bus 0x5 vendor 0x56a product 0x81 version 0x100
Input device name: "WACOM Pen Tablet"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (Sync)
  Event type 1 (Key)
    Event code 256 (Btn0)
    Event code 257 (Btn1)
    Event code 272 (LeftBtn)
    Event code 273 (RightBtn)
    Event code 274 (MiddleBtn)
    Event code 320 (ToolPen)
    Event code 321 (ToolRubber)
    Event code 325 (ToolFinger)
    Event code 326 (ToolMouse)
    Event code 330 (Touch)
    Event code 331 (Stylus)
    Event code 332 (Stylus2)
  Event type 2 (Relative)
    Event code 0 (X)
    Event code 1 (Y)
    Event code 8 (Wheel)
  Event type 3 (Absolute)
    Event code 0 (X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    16704
      Fuzz       4
    Event code 1 (Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    12064
      Fuzz       4
    Event code 24 (Pressure)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      511
    Event code 25 (Distance)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max       32
  Event type 4 (Misc)
    Event code 0 (Serial)
    Event code 4 (ScanCode)
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1280338937.153325, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -11
Event: time 1280338937.153329, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.158322, type 2 (Relative), code 0 (X), value -9
Event: time 1280338937.158326, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -5
Event: time 1280338937.158328, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.160320, type 2 (Relative), code 0 (X), value -7
Event: time 1280338937.160323, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -2
Event: time 1280338937.160325, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.176324, type 2 (Relative), code 0 (X), value -9
Event: time 1280338937.176328, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -1
Event: time 1280338937.176329, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.216328, type 2 (Relative), code 0 (X), value -13
Event: time 1280338937.216332, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -2
Event: time 1280338937.216334, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.260335, type 2 (Relative), code 0 (X), value -18
Event: time 1280338937.260338, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -2
Event: time 1280338937.260340, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.270322, type 2 (Relative), code 0 (X), value -41
Event: time 1280338937.270326, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -2
Event: time 1280338937.270328, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.288325, type 2 (Relative), code 0 (X), value -17
Event: time 1280338937.288329, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -3
Event: time 1280338937.288332, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.939320, type 4 (Misc), code 4 (ScanCode), value 90001
Event: time 1280338937.939324, type 1 (Key), code 272 (LeftBtn), value 1
Event: time 1280338937.939331, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.958314, type 2 (Relative), code 0 (X), value 22
Event: time 1280338937.958318, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -4
Event: time 1280338937.958320, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.968309, type 2 (Relative), code 0 (X), value 25
Event: time 1280338937.968312, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -4
Event: time 1280338937.968314, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.980307, type 2 (Relative), code 0 (X), value 24
Event: time 1280338937.980310, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -4
Event: time 1280338937.980312, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1280338937.998313, type 2 (Relative), code 0 (X), value 26
Event: time 1280338937.998316, type 2 (Relative), code 1 (Y), value -5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLUTION] Install kernel 2.6.34 or newer, or use kernel 2.6.32 or older. 2.6.33 seems to have problems with this pad.

Answer (score 0):

See if this project helps:

[The Linux Wacom Project](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/)

> The Linux Wacom Project manages the
>   drivers, libraries, and documentation
>   for configuring and running Wacom
>   tablets under the Linux operating
>   system. It contains diagnostic
>   applications as well as updated kernel
>   drivers and XFree86/Xorg XInput
>   drivers.
>
> Supported Serial Devices
>   [...]
>   **Graphire & Intuos series**

Comment: I've already been through that ... didn't helped. Sorry.

Comment: @Patkos Csaba: Do you use the last linuxwacom version 0.8.8-6 dated 2010-07-15? Also see this thread : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=25151

Comment: I do use know the latest driver ... see my update on the post.

Comment: @Patkos Csaba: You should verify what you have done against the Linux Wacom HOWTO, step by step. If EVERY little detail checks thru correctly, then you can go on the Linux Wacom forums asking for further help from the developers. But you need first to follow the HOWTO really exactly, to avoid being flamed.

Comment: @Patkos Csaba: Did you abandon this post?

Comment: No, I did not abandon it ... I'm here and listening.
I also checked, and rechecked, remade, retested all the tutorials and documentations from the the linuxwacom project. Unfortunately I have no further information or any kind of success.

All I managed to achieve is have X.org recognize the tablet and show that it's detected in the xorg.0.log, but nothing else. 

So, unless I am getting a definitive answer / solution, you will have half of the bounty.

Comment: @Patkos Csaba: The bounty isn't the most important part. My last gasp before sending you to the developers is this Ubuntu thread : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=674738. But before that, look at this very interesting article http://cs.ozerki.net/zap/wacom-bt/, with the developer's email at the end (russian).